# Is it possible to force SpriteKit to respect depth buffer in Metal with a SKRenderer?

Tags: sprite-kit, metal

I want to mix SpriteKit and Metal, and I found that there is a special class for that - [SKRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skrenderer). But, as I see, it can only draw whole `SKScene` as a single layer above all screen. So, can it use the depth buffer and `zPosition` property for the proper rendering? For example, if my scene contains two `SKNode`s, and I want to draw "Metal object" between them?

I see in a GPU debugger that every `SKNode` is rendered with a separate draw call (even more that one, actually), so, in theory, it's possible to use `SKNode.zPosition` not only for sorting inside `SKScene`. For example, they can just translate it into viewport's z-position as is (and, of course, keep depth test).

The reason why I think that it's possible is that in the documentation, I see this sentence:

> For example, you might write the environmental effects layer of your app that does fog, clouds, and rain, with custom Metal shaders, and continue to layer content below and above that with SpriteKit.

and I just can't believe that as "continue to layer content below and above that with SpriteKit" they mean "OK, you can create two different SKScenes".

Comment: When inspecting a GPU Capure in Xcode, I see that SpriteKit does not write to the depth buffer. In my scenario, an instance of `SK3DNode` _does_ use the depth buffer (although that can be disabled in `SCNMaterial`), and subsequently draws on top of everything else (other `SKNodes` with a higher/lower `zPosition` do not alter the depth buffer so do not affect the SK3DNode draw call unfortunately). So unless we can tell SpriteKit to write to the depth buffer, my guess is you need multiple SKScenes.